# Read large values in Excel sheet

Tags: c#, excel

I have large data nearly about 5,00,000 of record.I have to write it to Excel..Is it possible to read such huge amount of data in excel sheet.Are there any better  ways to do so

Comment: "A lakh is a unit in the South Asian numbering system equal to one hundred thousand (100,000; 105), written as 1,00000", Wikipedia

Comment: Please use SI units when dealing with numbers. *Lakhs* are too localised. To answer your question, Excel 2007 and above can handle approx 1 million rows, if your machine has the memory available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel 2010 can have a Worksheet size - 65,536 rows by 256 columns as shown on this link http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP005199291.aspx

I would suggest that you create .csv file's in C# at runtime from the results with a batch of 1 Lakh each query or if possible 1/2 lakh so you will have 5 - 10 calls but it will speed up your process returned by your stored procedure

These .csv files can be opened in Excel so you can still use excel as the application at the end

Also please see this link hence i did not recommend you using Automation of Office

> Paragraph taken from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757 Microsoft
>   does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of
>   Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive
>   client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT
>   Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or
>   deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

Answer (score 0):

Excel 2007 and above can handle approx 1 million rows, if your machine has the memory available.

It would probably be better to use a database, however.